# What is causing this drain current ringing

Tags: mosfet, buck-boost, ringing, current-drain

This is 4 kW Buck boost, Vin Min = 200 V. L = 600uH, switch used is C3M0065100K. With just 2.4 kW power, I notice the high Di/Dt on bottom switch drain current. Top and bottom switches have RCD snubber as shown in 2nd image.

I would like to understand what is causing this high Di/Dt and how to solve this.

My assumption is L and parasitic MOSFET capacitance are causing this, but I'm not sure which of the MOSFET capacitances is causing this. What can I do to reduce this without adding more snubbers? Layout seems very good in this case, the MOSFET loop area is minimum with wide multi plane carrying this current.

[Please excuse inverted drain current waveform]

[image: Illustrative only: Buck Boost power circuit]

[image]

[image: Id of bottom mosfet (inverted waveform)]
[image: Id Of Bottom Mosfet , Zoomed , Inverted waveform]

Comment: 1) you should draw the complete schematic that you're using, not two parts where it is completely unclear how they connect. 2) Lear to live with this ringing, **you cannot avoid it** you can only **minimize it**, by - you guessed it - adding a snubber network. The ringing is energy being transferred between the circuit's parasitics. This energy will need to "go somewhere". That's why we use snubber networks, to absorb and dissipate that energy.

Answer (score 4):

Often, part of the ringing is an artifact due to the way the scope probes are grounded. Connect the second channel in the scope the exact same way, except that the tip of the probe is connected to the same point as the two probes' ground clips. If channel 2 shows the same ringing, it's due to the way the scope probes are grounded.

Specifically, if the scope is grounded to earth through its power cord, and the switchmode circuit is grounded to earth through its power supply (either directly, or through a series capacitor inside the supply) you have a ground loop.

Regardless, at least part of the ringing is actually there. Layout is often the main culprit. Circuits built "mid-air" will ring like a banshee. Circuits built on a good ground plane, with a single star-ground to connect the power circuit and the drive circuit, are ideal.

Comment: I am sorry but i beleive you didnt read my question well. The ringing here (and the waveforms show ) are Drain current ringing. Its not voltage (not VDS) . The measurement has no errors as it was done by isolated rogowski probe . Parasitics of layout is not causing this from what i understand, this if caused by L (or leakage of L) with Mosfet capacitance, But i am not sure which is it exactly and were do i need to tune my circuit to reduce it. 30A ringing on a 10A waveform is unacceptable for me.

Comment: You are correct, I missed the "current" part. Sorry. One look at the plots told me that that was voltage, not current.

Comment: No worries, I dont blame you.. I wonder ,even the three people who voted this as right answer also didnt read the question.. Lol